# BufferedReader() returning empty string when there are more strings in the file?

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedreader

My txt file looks like this:

```
data;data2;data3;data4..........up till data3146
```

When I open the txt file in notepad I see it in the form given above.
But when I copy paste the first few lines to another place, There is a 1 line gap b/w data1 and everything else. Because of this I am getting problems while accessing the file in Java and using the data with a bufferedreader in a loop. How can I correct this? I can't remove the empty line as it is not even visible in the original file.

Comment: Try opening it in Notepad++ ;)<br />
(Propably you will have to enable showing hidden characters)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore the blank line(s). Something like this -

```
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this way:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("your file path")));
    String str = null;
    while((str = reader.readLine())!=null) {
        if (str.matches("[' ']+")) {
            continue;
        } else {
            // to do 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need an `else` after `continue`, or `break` or `return` or `throw` either for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is in the line endings. Basically you can skip the empty lines:

```
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if ("".equals(line.trim()) {
    continue;
  }
  // do your stuff here
}
```